# Can We Auto-generate Controllers and Views Using Dapper

Tags: .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, crud, dapper

I am working with dapper with c# and mssql . Is there any way that we can autogenerate Controllers and views with dapper as we do with EF.

I thought [DapperExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DapperExtensions/) will work as they specified

> A small library that complements Dapper by adding basic CRUD operations (Get, Insert, Update, Delete) for your POCOs.

Comment: As far as I know (and I wrote the core library): "no"

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for reply. Do you have any info about what dapperextensions is offering

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here, and say that it adds basic CRUD operations (Get, Insert, Update, Delete) for your POCOs.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't any possibility to auto generate Controllers and views with dapper as we do with EF